# generic way of getting class name

Tags: java

Would what be a static equivalent of a dynamic

> String CLASS_NAME = this.getClass().getCanonicalName()

Note that the following is not what i'm looking for since it specifically refers to a particular class. I'd like to refer to class name outside of a method (ie in the static {} section)

> static String CLASS_NAME = Foo.class.getCanonicalName()

THanks.

Comment: Shouldn't the first be `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`?

Comment: Instead of writing the name by hand?

Comment: Why do you need generics if you know what type you're in (since you want to use a `static` block)?

Comment: @Ken generic as in non-specific, not java generics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
public static <T> String getCanonicalName() {
    return T.class.getCanonicalName();
}
```

But I'm sure that you've already figured out that this does not work. This is because Java generics rely on type erasure. That is, `T` only exists at compile time. At run time, `T` is no longer accessible.

To do this generically, you must use an instance of the type as you did in your first example.

### Edit

After realizing the true nature of your question, I do not come bearing a direct answer.

I have seen certain "hacks" like the following

```
static String ClassName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace[0].getClassName();
```

This gets the name of the class, but I'm pretty sure it will not be the same as that returned by `getCanonicalName()`, and I really don't know of a way to transform the output  of `getClassName()` into the output of `getCanonicalName()`.

I think it there are is a change to the Java language that would have really helped developers write intuitive code: if some sort of `self` keyword to could be added refer to the current class it would simplify any scenario like yours, by allowing you to write things like `self.class.getCanonicalName()`. But, as things stand, we don't have that, so what you'd like to do isn't directly possible.

There are other possible workarounds. For example, you can try something like:

```
 static String ClassName = null;

 public Foo() {
     if(ClassName == null)
         ClassName = this.getClass().getCanonicalName();
 }
```

But that requires your class to be constructible, which is not always desirable. It's also not nearly as straightforward as it could be if we had a `self` keyword.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I understand your question - did you try `this.getClass().getCanonicalName()`?

Comment: @Saideira: I'm lost. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @home: His new answer is pretty self descriptive.

Comment: @home I want to know if its possible to get a class name in a generic name without having an instance of it

Comment: @Ken Wayne VanderLinde: Yeah, looks like your answer is the right one :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a horrible hack

```
class MyClass{
    private static String cannonicalName;
    static{
      cannonicalName = new Object(){}.getEnclosingClass().getCannonicalName();
    }    
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?
It does give you the class name in a generic and static way, but you create an anonymous class just for it.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite understanding what you mean, perhaps this is what you are after:

```
public static String getCanonicalName(Class<?> clazz){
    return clazz.getCanonicalName();
}
```